# Tcl: How can I search a nested list in Tcl 8.4?

Tags: list, search, tcl

I have a nested list as follows:

```
set myList {
   {first apples dollars}
   {second bananas euros}
   {third pears pesos}
}
```

In Tcl 8.7, I can use `lsearch -index 2` (e.g.) if I want to find the type of fruit I'm selling in euros:

```
set myFruit [lindex $myList [lsearch -index 2 $myList "euros"] 1]
puts $myFruit    
# returns bananas
```

But how do I do that in Tcl 8.4 where the `-index` switch doesn't exist? Is there a shortcut, or will I have to use a `foreach`?

I would like to do this with TCl's native functionality, if possible, and not via any additional packages (which I unfortunately cannot use for my particular project).

Comment: Why on earth are you stuck with 8.4? It's **OLD AND UNSUPPORTED**. Whoever is forcing you into that situation Is Bad And Should Feel Bad. It's 2019, not 2004!

Comment: There can be many reasons to be stuck on tcl 8.4, Many customers freeze changes if nothing is broken, they may demand occasional patches but Tcl may not be the one that qualifies for upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the wildcard option of `lsearch` might be what you are looking for?

```
set myList {
   {first apples dollars}
   {second bananas euros}
   {third pears pesos}
}

set myFruit [lindex $myList [lsearch $myList "*euros*"] 1]
puts $myFruit
```

Though the above would also match the word 'neuroscience' for example, so you could use something like the below if that's a possibility:

```
lsearch -regexp $myList {\yeuros\y}
```

---

If it gets more complex, like, if you want to match the entire sub-element (and therefore not want to match `euros` in the element `{forth kiwi "0.5 euros each"}` then instead of trying to make the search more flexible, I believe it would be much easier to use a loop:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $myList]} {incr i} {
    if {"euros" in [split [lindex $myList $i]]} {
        set myFruit [lindex $myList $i]
        puts $myFruit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more an extension to Jerry's answer:

If going down the `regexp` route, and you can guarantee that the input list of lists is regular in the sense of a sanitized Tcl-list string representation, then you can have `regexp` do all the work:

```
 lindex [regexp -all -inline {([^\s]+)\s+euros\}} $myList] 1
```

This also covers for the case of multiple sub-lists having `euros` as elements.

```
 foreach {_ v}  [regexp -all -inline {([^\s]+)\s+euros\}} $myList] {puts $v}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [589332](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893332/tcl-lsearch-on-list-of-list):

```
package require Tclx

set somelist {{aaa 1} {bbb 2} {ccc 1}}
set searchTerm "bbb"
if {[keylget somelist $searchTerm myvar]} {
    puts "Found instance of $searchTerm, value is: $myvar"
}
```

> The keylget command in this syntax returns 1 if found, 0 if not. The value next to bbb (2) is then placed in the variable myvar. Note that there should be no dollar sign ($) in front of somelist in the keylget command.

So for your example that would be:

```
set searchTerm "euros"
if {[keylget myList $searchTerm myFruit]} {
    puts $myFruit
}
```

(Not marking this as a duplicate because 589332 didn't deal with v8.4 specifically; someone just happened to mention it in one of the answers.)

Comment: How could I achieve the original goal without use of a package (which in addition to being stuck with 8.4 is another limitation I currently have - no ability/permission to load packages)

Comment: In that case I think you're probably stuck with a `foreach`.